# Scheduling a set of transactions to be executed on a basis

Tags: solidity, scheduling, arbitrum

I am searching for a platform that can help me to have a particular function of my smart contract executed on a regular basis.

I have found a couple of solutions, but none is useful as my contract is deployed on Arbitrum Testnet and those platform does not support Arbitrum.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only service that I know of is [keep3r](https://keep3r.network/) but it's only available on ethereum.

A possible solution would be to reward users that call that function in some way or make that function call with some other function call that the users will perform (eg deposit, withdraw if it's vault kind of thing).